# Python: plotting sift points returns points off the pictures

Tags: python, computer-vision, sift

I'm using the sift implementation along with code found in the "Programming Computer Vision with Python".

While using the plotMatches function in vision.py (equivalent to the plot_matches() function to the book), some of the points plotted aren't even on the image: 
[image: Output of the results]

As you can see, most of the points aren't on either of the image.

This may be the result of a change I had to make to my plotMatches() function:

```
        for i, m in enumerate(matchscores):
            if i > 0:
                 lab.plot([locs1[i][1], locs2[i][1] + cols1],
                 [locs1[i][0], locs2[i][0]], 'c')
```

The original code:

```
        for i, m in enumerate(matchscores):
            if i > 0:
                lab.plot([locs1[i][1], locs2[m][1] + cols1],
                [locs1[i][0], locs2[m][0]], 'c')
```

Would throw the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/peter-brown/AI/Markus/ImageRecognition.py", line 37,     in <module>
     sch.plotMatches(image, image2, l1, l2, matches, show_below=False)
     File "/home/peter-brown/AI/Markus/vision.py", line 199, in    plotMatches
     lab.plot([locs1[i][1], locs2[m][1] + cols1],
     IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

By changing any 'm' used in the code, the program would work, but it would output incorrectly.

Why does the output not correspond to the image, and how can i change the plotMatches function to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `matplotlib`, the `x` and `y` coordinates are flipped. From your image it looks like you are interpreting all `x` coordinates as `y` coordinates and vice-versa. From your function, this is a simple change:

```
for i, m in enumerate(matchscores):
        if i > 0:
             lab.plot([locs1[i][0], locs2[i][0] + cols1],
             [locs1[i][1], locs2[i][1]], 'c')
```